# How to determine if an index is a system index in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have written the query below to help me determine which indexes need to be reorganised or reindexed and would like to know how to exclude system indexes from the results:

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME([stats].[object_id]) AS [TableName], 
  i.name AS [IndexName],
  index_type_desc,
  avg_fragmentation_in_percent,
  fragment_count,
  avg_fragment_size_in_pages
FROM
[sys].[dm_db_index_physical_stats](DB_ID(), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL) AS stats
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.indexes AS i ON i.object_id = stats.object_id
                                            AND i.index_id = stats.index_id
WHERE i.name is not null 
ORDER BY [TableName] asc
```

The results from this give me what I need, however they also include system indexes, which I do not want to include. After doing some research into possible solutions one I have seen is to look at the 'is_ms_shipped' field of the table, therefore to include the following in the join in the query:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.tables AS t on t.object_id = stats.object_id
```

And then include the following in the where clause:

```
and t.is_ms_shipped = 0
```

This does exclude some, but not all system tables. What is the preferred way to determine whether an index is a system index?

I could exclude them by name, but this does not seem very elegant.

The version of SQL Server I am using is 2012.

Answer (score 1):

After looking into possible solutions for this issue the only table system index that I receive after excluding the 'is_ms_shipped' is from the 'sysdiagrams' table so I just exclude this table in the where clause:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.tables AS t on t.object_id = stats.object_id
WHERE (i.name IS NOT NULL) and (t.is_ms_shipped = 0) and (t.name != 'sysdiagrams')
```

Comment: see also http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/60555/how-to-retrieve-whether-database-has-any-tables/60556#60556